Simulation problem in half bridge leg of an inverter
I am simulating Half Bridge Leg on an inverter. From the simulation, I could not understand why I was not getting proper dead time between high and low side fets. However, I set a delay time of 150ns for a low-side voltage pulse. my question is why I am not getting 150ns delay time while switching two FETs.
You can see from the graph that the reason for the cross-conduction or shoot-through is due to the dead time.
how can I get a proper dead time or delay time between two FETs? So could somebody help me or guide me regarding my problem?

Here, I attached the gate signal of High side and low side where one can see dead time is only 90-100ns

I think in the simulation there was no proper dead time between two Fets therefore I observed the shoot-through effect. Please correct me if I am wrong.

@Antonio51
As per your suggestion, I increased the delay time of V2 to 250ns and got the same result as I got with 150ns.

@hennep
Used Mosfets has a 51nc total gate charge and
I also change the value of V1 and V2 to 17V and the gate resistor to 30 ohms. However, I can still observe the shoot-through or cross-conduction effects in my simulation.


Is it the "high" current id(M1) the question ?

Hello Antonio,
yes and also why I did not get proper delay on gate pulse
you can seen from figure gate to source voltage waveforms

please edit the post ... right now, it does not contain a question  ... the comment you wrote is not a part of the question

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Looks like cross conduction to me. Have you tried to increase your deadtime?

Increase in parameters for V2 the 150 ns (-> 250ns) for the delay ... If the current peak gets "lower", then it is a "cross-conduction".

@Antonio51 I increased the parameter for V2 to 250ns as per your suggestion.
my question is why I am not getting 250ns delay time while switching two FETs.
You can see from the graph that the reason for the cross-conduction is due to the dead time.
how can I get a proper dead time or delay time between two FETs?

@krunalpatel I haven't looked up the gate charge of the used mosfet. I guess that 47 ohm is a bit high and that it creates an RC time that matches the dead time. Try raising the voltage for the gate from 12 to 17V and lower the 47 ohm.

(@krunalpatel Please do not try to edit someone else's post, to reply to them. That is never the correct etiquette on Stack Exchange. I rejected that edit. In any case, that user said they had intended their post to be a comment, so I have converted it to be a comment above. You can add your own comment to respond, as usual. || The list of allowed uses of edits here may be useful to you. Also this linked from the FAQ.)

The gate capacitance of your MOSFET can be 4900pF.  With a 47-ohm resistor, this leads to an RC time constant of 230 microseconds. This will help you calculate your dead time.
You must provide dead time at both switch points.  Shifting one of the square waves as you have done provides dead time at one switching polarity, but causes overlap on the other. To provide dead times at both switching points, your switching waveforms cannot be symmetrical square waves but must have a duty cycle less than 50%.
Good luck!
